# the maximum length of push notifcation message ios

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to know what is the maximum length of the message sent for push notification, because in my testing issue, I recognized that I have problem in it, when I am trying to send a short message, push notification works well, but if I put a message that has more than 30 characters, the device doesn't receive the push notification.

In my php code, I have this:

```
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

Is it related or not? and how can I adjust the length of the message?

In my code, I use UTF-8 encoding, is it related also?

Please help, thank you per advance!

Answer (score 6):

for iOS maximum length for Push notification message is 256 bytes.

Comment: I've searched on google, and I get this answer, but my question was, I have a problem with the maximum length, is there any method allows me to adjust the length????

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) (and previous answers) states that your payload is restricted to 256 bytes, i.e. any message that is longer will be refused by the system.

The typical way of dealing with this restriction is to pass a notification id with your push notification and request the full payload directly from your server when entering the app from that push notification.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes;

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are intended to be small; the payload size can be no more than 256 bytes, **You can't adjust the length.**`

Push notifications whose payload exceeds 256 bytes will not be accepted by APNS.

Comment: the characters are in utf-8 encoding, and the max size is 39 characters, when I put 40 characters it will be rejected by APNS!, because my data is in arabic!

Comment: please check this link....https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easyapns/xR3MItcXOjA

Comment: thank you, I will check by Monday, and I will give you a feedback :)